# How to get the $view outside of controller

Tags: symfony

I understand that the $view can be accessed within a rendered template file, but I wonder if there is anyway I can get it elsewhere?

The reason is that I'm building SF2 on top of a classic/legacy system and there are certain templates that cannot be rendered with the normal render method. However, I still want to be able to access the view helper inside those template, so I want to init a global $view which can be used in these legacy templates

Answer (score 1):

These helpers are provided in the `PhpEngine` class in the Templating component ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating.html)). You can acces this class with the `templating.engine.php` service (you need to have PHP enabled as a templating engine).

From a controller it will look like this:

```php
// ...
public function fooAction(...)
{
    // ...
    $template = $this->get('templating.engine.php')->render(...);
}
```

If you are using another class, you should use DI:

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Foo.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class Foo
{
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        // ...
        $template = $this->templating->render(...);
    }
}
```

```yml
// app/config.yml
services:
    acme_demo:
        foo:
            class: Acme\DemoBundle\Foo
            arguments: [@templating.engine.php]
```

More about DI in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html).

Comment: thank you. I just wonder, what if I use twig and php template at the same time?

Comment: You can't mix Twig and PHP in one template. And make one template in PHP and the other in Twig isn't correct either, I suggest to use only one template format in a bundle. If you want the Twig engine, you can use the `twig` service (`templating` will work too, I think) and there is a service which checks if the template uses PHP or Twig, but I don't know the name now (just var_dump the `$this->container->getServiceIds()` in your controller and you will find it)